# How do I make Vue 2 Provide / Inject API reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I set up my code as follows, and I was able to update `checkout_info` in App.vue from the setter in SomeComponent.vue, but the getter in SomeComponent.vue is not reactive.

```js
// App.vue
export default {
    provide() {
        return {
            checkout_info: this.checkout_info,
            updateCheckoutInfo: this.updateCheckoutInfo
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            checkout_info: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateCheckoutInfo(key, value) {
            this.checkout_info[key] = value
        }
    }
}
```

```js
// SomeComponent.vue
export default {
    inject: ['checkout_info', 'updateCheckoutInfo']
    computed: {
        deliveryAddress: {
            get() { return this.checkout_info.delivery_address }, // <---- Not reactive??
            set(value) { return this.updateCheckoutInfo('delivery_address', value) }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I [found the answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeIKd-CicK8) after many hours of searching. You have to use `Object.defineProperty` to make it reactive. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but this is a working example.

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            checkout_info: {},
        }
    },
    provide() {
        const appData = {}

        Object.defineProperty(appData, "checkout_info", {
            enumerable: true,
            get: () => this.checkout_info,
        })

        return {
            updateCheckoutInfo: this.updateCheckoutInfo,
            appData,
        }
    }
}
```

You can later access it via `this.appData.checkout_info`

Comment: is the `provide` and `inject` something that is meant to be used natively in Vue 3 and using it in Vue 2 requires work arounds?

Comment: this is a great answer, thank you! just be careful not to declare provide as arrow provide: () => {...} because the you will not have a this and the solution falls apart.

Answer (score 6):

This note from official documentation.

> Note: the provide and inject bindings are NOT reactive. This is
> intentional. However, if you pass down an observed object, properties
> on that object do remain reactive.

I think this is the answer to your question.

source:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject

Comment: It's suppose to be reactive if you pass in a reactive property. I'm passing in a reactive data, and therefore should be tracked by Vue?

Comment: IMO this statement is not very helpful. also the examples you find for this do not work.

Answer (score 4):

I would put the values in an object:

```js
var Provider = {
  provide() {
    return {
       my_data: this.my_data
     };
  },
  data(){
    const my_data = {
      foo: '1',
      fuu: '2'
    };
    return {
      my_data;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var Child = {
  inject: ['my_data'],
  data(){
   console.log(my_data.foo);
   return {};
  },
}
```

When are object properties they are reactive. I don't know if this is the correct solution but it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue.js 2.7 or later, which has Composition API built-in, you can import and use 'computed' to make provided data reactive:

**Parent Component:**

```
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  provide() {
    return {
      foo: computed(() => this.bar)
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      bar: 'Hello World'
    }
  }
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
export default {
  inject: ['foo']
}
```